# Why was this "question caused by a typo" deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

I want to know why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65255353/13552470) question that has a user's upvoted answer and my upvoted &  accepted answer on it got deleted. Screenshot of the deleted post:

[image]

For one, the close reason is that it was caused by a typo, but I don't see that as the case;
they *thought* that the `update` function gets called outside the loop, when it should be called inside the loop. There was no indentation error, the program simply acted differently from the intended behavior.

Besides pointing out the issue, I've also included more helpful information explaining some key points to the OP. I would've simply voted to undelete, but because a mod deleted it, I couldn't.

Comment: Because it had no future value. We frequently delete bad questions too, it's like half the site's moderation mechanic

Comment: @Zoe What makes you think it has no future value??

Comment: I have a ton of metrics for that, but in this specific case, it's one of those bugs that're caused by bad indentation in an intent-sensitive language, and that if allowed would cause a massive flood of questions misunderstanding how intentation works in Python. I won't lose any sleep on closing these questions as typos, because in the case of Python, they are.

Comment: @Zoe Like I said, the OP thought that the `update` function didn't belong in the loop, **not** how they neglected to indent that line.

Comment: You yourself have said it's an indentation error; the function was poorly intended, and as a result was called outside instead of inside the loop. You've even illustrated the proper placement in the answer, with no mention of it being a misunderstanding. You have no proof that OP claimed that. I looked at the raw question, and there's no mention of it. If it argued about the .flip method, that would've been a different question, but it didn't. Ergo, typo. I completely support the typo closure and subsequent deletion.

Comment: @AnnZen: I think you're guessing on what op might have thought. Noone knows whether this was caused because op thinks that flip should be outside of the loop or because op simply forgot to indent. There is even a second answer on the question that thinks it's an indentation error.

Comment: @Zoe *"You yourself have said it's an indentation error"* No I haven't.

Comment: @BDL Actually, they didn't say anything about indentation errors.

Comment: Noticed that after the fact, but you've illustrated the correct indentation once again without mentioning that it's a misunderstanding of how it's meant to be used, because you can't prove it's a misunderstanding in how it's meant to be used.

Comment: @Zoe Good point, I just added it.

Comment: The addition to your answer still doesn't make the situation better. The question is still likely to be based on a misunderstanding; see BDLs comment and the other answer on the SO question.

Comment: @Zoe I think you're guessing on what op might have thought.

Comment: Also, BDLs ocmment matters because even if you try to make the assumption OP misunderstood, assuming a misunderstanding requires knowing what OP is thinking, where as the existence of an indentation error is completely objective. There are 4 spaces (or a tab or whatever other form of indentation character you prefer) missing that broke the code, regardless of what you feel like putting in your answer

Comment: @Zoe Actually, it's more like the other way around; the code they used had a mistake in it, it's completely objective that the code was intended to be that way, and requires an explanation on why it should be different.

Comment: @Zoe: I actually think that both reasons are equally likely. I just don't think that in either case the question as it stands now serves any purpose because even if Ann Zen's explanation is what op was looking for, it is impossible to search/find this question if you have the same problem.

Comment: " it's completely objective that the code was intended to be that way" - you mean it's intended to be broken? By that metric, no questions on SO actually have broken code, but code decided to break. It's also perfectly possible to miss indentation issues. There's a reason typos exist. I recently had one because I left out an `&`, which triggered copying instead of referencing, which essentially broke the entire thing. Spent half an  hour noticing that, so no, there's a very real chance it wasn't intentional

Comment: @BDL *"it is impossible to search/find this question if you have the same problem."* Wrong. It is very likely a user would search something along the lines of "Pygame background image not fully loading", and find that post.

Comment: @Zoe *"you mean it's intended to be broken?"* no. What I mean is that they didn't "accidentally" stuff in some code they didn't mean to.

Comment: You mean like [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878264/background-image-not-appearing-in-pygame)?

Comment: No, but the indentation could be accidental. That doesn't make it any less of a typo - it's usually the definition of a typo in code

Comment: @Zoe Yeah! It has 1K views, so this post might be very helpful as well. It's not a duplicate, they situations are different.

Comment: Yeah, because this situation _was caused by a typo_ leaving it outside the loop. That specific bit of information is what makes it near or entirely impossible to search for

Comment: @Zoe This situation *is not necessarily cause by a typo*, meaning it could be reopened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226132/discussion-between-ann-zen-and-zoe).

Comment: It already has no future value. It was caused by a minor indentation issue that could've easily been uncovered by looking at the dupe I linked and generalized in a way that tried to compare the difference between working code and non-working code. I still won't lose any sleep over that question being nuked, and I probably would've thrown in a delvote if I noticed before it was deleted. Also, if we allow questions like this, SO would get more trash that stays open. Typo implies accidental, and since we work off what we have (the question and its contents), we say it's a typo and move on

Comment: The reason I mentioned different context earlier is because in a case where the question specifically asks specifically about general usage, it might be on-topic (depends on the exact wording and whatnot). In _this specific case_, however, it's not. Disregard the 10 rep you lost for a second and try to look at this objectively instead.

Comment: I wish @Zoe would have posted an answer so I could have upvoted it, instead of all these back-and-forth comments...

Comment: @CodyGray I see. Just a reminder, you can upvote their comments :)

Answer (score 17):

As @Zoe said

> Because it had no future value

You simply fixed the issue of a particular code so I doubt someone in the future will be writing the exact same code and facing the exact same issue.

In order to give a *value* to the question you can try to make your answer a generic one addressing the indentation issue and explaining why it's important when writing a Python code. Wait, this sounds like the basics of Python so I am pretty sure there is a ton of duplicates explaining this.

After 5 seconds of searching, I got this: [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45621722/8620333)

---

If you are not convinced with that close reason we can close the question as a duplicate of the above one (or a better one<sup>1</sup>) and we delete it later since it's a trivial nth-duplicate because I am pretty sure people face indentation issue everyday.

<sub>1: I am not a python expert so I am pretty sure there is a more suitable question. In all the cases, I am convinced that there is a trivial duplicate.</sub>

Comment: "*I doubt someone in the future will be writing the exact same code and facing the exact same issue.*" It's really likely that a user would think that the `update` function belong out of the loop, and wonder why the image is not fully displayed.

Comment: *"After 5 seconds of searching I got this"* this did not involve any error, so how would the user know to search that?

Comment: *"we can close the question as a duplicate of the above"* how? There is no indentation error in the OP's code, it runs smoothly, but not how they wanted it to.

Comment: @AnnZen *so how would the user know to search that?* --> it's not for the user to search, it's for your and other more experienced user to point to the duplicate. This is the purpose of the duplicate.

Comment: There is no indentation error in the OP's code, so it can't be that duplicate.

Comment: @AnnZen don't make the common mistake of reading only titles. No one said there is an indentation **error**. I never used the word error in my answer (it's only the title of the linked question). I said that the main issue was caused by a missed indentation. If you understand how indendattion works you will not make the same mistake. The question I used is a canonical one detailing indentation

Comment: The body of the post says there's an indentation error as well.